# nginx: Redirect https traffic without subdomain to subdomain (non-www to www)

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, https

My current ssl certificate covers the subdomains www.example.com and static.example.com

So if a users try to access my site via https://example.com I want to redirect him to https://www.example.com .

How can I do that within in my nginx conf?

I know that similiar questions have been asked here, but I could not find the solution here.

Comment: I think this thread solves the underlying problem with a better answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/748623/nginx-ssl-always-redirect-to-one-of-two-https-subdomains

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should get a certificate valid both for `example.com` and `www.example.com` (you can get it for free from [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) or [WoSign](http://www.wosign.com/english/index.htm)). Then make sure you got SNI enabled in your nginx (should be there by default). Then just add the following to your nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl spdy;
    listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/example.com.key;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Not useful in their case as they specify their certificate doesn't cover example.com, only www. and static.example.com.

Comment: well, yes, he needs to get another certificate, i've updated my answer...