# nginx / ssl: Always redirect to one of two https subdomains

Tags: nginx, ssl, subdomain

My webserver supports the following two subdomains:

- https://www.example.com
- https://en.example.com

I want to create my nginx config so that:

1. http://en.example.com$request_uri => https://en.example.com$request_uri
2. http://www.example.com$request_uri => https://www.example.com$request_uri
3. Every other subdomain independent of http or https => https://www.example.com$request_uri

I could not find any solution online that solves this problem. Can anybody help me out with the correct nginx config.

Comment: I want this question to exist and this is the duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/748617/nginx-redirect-https-traffic-without-subdomain-to-subdomain-non-www-to-www

I think this questions and Anubioz answer here gives other people a better understanding of nginx then the other question i posted.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should understand that you can't make a "transparent" https redirection from `https://something.example.com` to `https://www.example.com` if your SSL certificate doesn't support `something.example.com` domain. It will show `Your connection is not secure` error or similar, when accessed. However, you should be able to redirect from `http://*.example.com` to `https://www.example.com` without any troubles. To do that, add the following on top of your `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

It should redirect any request to your IP to `https://www.example.com`

Then we add configurations for specific redirects. This one for `http://en.example.com` -> `https://en.example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name en.example.com;
    return 301 https://en.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This one for `http://www.example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

And finally, we add configuration for "real" domains that should serve desired content via SSL. This one for `http://www.example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/www.example.com.key;
    server_name www.example.com;
    <your www.example.com server config here>
    ...
    </your www.example.com server config here>
}
```

This one for `http://en.example.com`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/en.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/en.example.com.key;
    server_name en.example.com;
    <your en.example.com server config here>
    ...
    </your en.example.com server config here>
}
```

Comment: May be you should consider adding some texts to explain how this code is going to solve the problem.

Comment: Sure, busy doing it atm....

Comment: just one thing I would take out spdy as the version of nginx is not stated and spdy is replaced with http2 in latest releases

Comment: yes, indeed, spdy is deprecated, there's no way to include both, so i'll edit my answer for most "generic" config...

Comment: This looks very good, thanks a lot. Does your answer also redirect non-subdomain traffic (http://example.com and https://example.com) correctly to https://www.example.com

Comment: Yes, the first block with `server_name  _;` redirects every possible subdomain and/or direct IP visit (i.e. `http://1.2.3.4/url`) to `https://example.com/url`